# How can I put the top panel on the bottom of screen?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I would like to put the top panel on the bottom of the screen like it is in Gnome. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you asking? It seems like you need to ask several questions - if so, please create separate questions. Also, please fix the title.

Comment: Hi Ronald, and welcome to askubuntu. This isn't a discussion site, rather it's a question and answer site. It differs from a traditional forum in that you are supposed to ask a specific questions that has a specific answer, so each thread is focused on a single issue. For more information, please see the FAQ http://askubuntu.com/faq

As for this question, you should rephrase it so it better resembles a question because, right now, it's at risk of being closed as 'Not a question'.

Comment: @ChrisWilson We don't have threads here, it's _questions_.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i'm aware, it isn't currently possible, short of editing the source code (and my guess is that a lot of things probably assume it is at the top at the moment, so you'd probably have to edit more than just a couple of lines)

i'd like to be proven wrong on this though

Comment: This is correct, it's currently not possible.

Answer (score -1):

`Right click` on it > `Properties`. Under `General` tab, change the `Orientation` to `Bottom`.

Comment: If he's using 11.04 & unity its not possible to do this

Comment: That only works with GNOME 2

Comment: Didn't saw the tiny tags!